# Static block is not executed before constructor

Tags: java

I am stuck in one problem.There are three classes
1.Teacher
2.TeacherEx
3.TeacherClass

I am making an static object of Teacher class `public static Teacher t`
When i am making 4 objects of `TeacherEx` in `TeacherClass` the  static block in `TeacherEx` is executing only once, whereas it has to be executed 4 times.
Can anyone explain me what exactly the problem is?

Posting all 3 classes
Teacher class

```
public class Teacher {
    public static String name;
    public static String subject;
    public static int  nolec;
}

public static class TeacherEx {

public int noStd;
public String place;
public static Teacher t;


public TeacherEx(int no, String p)
{
    noStd=no;
    place=p;

    t.name="prashantha";
    t.subject="Java_classes";
    t.nolec++;

    System.out.println("The nos of lec after creation class are "+t.nolec);

}


static{

    if(t==null)
    {
        t=new Teacher();
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Nothing");
    }

    System.out.println("The nos of lec before this class creation are  "+t.nolec);
}

}


public class TeacherClass {

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    TeacherEx a=new TeacherEx(45,"banglore");

    TeacherEx b=new TeacherEx(75,"Mumbai");


    TeacherEx c=new TeacherEx(49,"chennai");

    TeacherEx d=new TeacherEx(47,"Newyork");

}

}
```

Comment: There is no problem. The static block is executed when the class is initially loaded, which only happens once. If you want code to be executed on object instantiation, put it in the constructor.

Comment: Or ... to put it another way ... the problem is 1) you don't understand how statics and static initialization work, and 2) you probably shouldn't be using a `static` here at all.

Comment: I know static concepts.I was trying all possible things with static

Comment: Sorry. No.  If you think that (somehow) a `static` initialization will run more than once, you DO NOT understand `static`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static members of a class are not instance members. That means that they are attached (bound) to the class itself and not to the instances of the class. Here you have 4 instances of the `TeacherEx` class, but that does not matter for the static members. You can access `static` members even if you don't have any instances of the class.

Try it yourself:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    println(TeacherEx.t.toString());

}
```

Static blocks will be executed when the class is being initialized by the JVM at the runtime. Constructors on the other hand will be called when an actual instantiation (`new TeacherEx(...)`) is being executed at runtime.